# Remover parte de dados inseridos pelo usuário

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Estou desenvolvendo um site para envios de vídeos para professores, para isto, fiz um form com os seguintes campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Levando em consideração que ainda estou aprendendo PHP. Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com que, o link do youtube inserido pelo usuário, fosse preenchido da seguinte forma no mysql:

Link do vídeo inserido pelo usuário: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBk-ayp6yyU

Apartir do link, gostaria que apenas fosse para o mysql o code do vídeo, como exemplo:

**KBk-ayp6yyU**

Outro exemplo:

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**NZta28cFU3w**

No mysql: **NZta28cFU3w**

Como posso fazer isso? Segue abaixo o registrar_video:

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");

$nome_video = $_POST['nome_video'];
$disciplina  = $_POST['disciplina'];
$link_video  = $_POST['link_video'];
$coment_video  = $_POST['coment_video'];
$arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"];

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])){

    $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4)); //pega a extensao do arquivo
    $novo_nome = md5(time()) . $extensao; //define o nome do arquivo
    $diretorio = "upload/"; //define o diretorio para onde enviaremos o arquivo
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome); //efetua o upload
      $sql_logar = "INSERT INTO video_monitor (titulo_video, disciplina, link_video, coment_video, arquivo, data) 
      VALUES('$nome_video', '$disciplina', '$link_video', '$coment_video', '$novo_nome', NOW())";
      $exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error($conection));
  } else {
      $sql_logar = "INSERT INTO video_monitor (titulo_video, disciplina, link_video, coment_video, arquivo, data)
      VALUES ('$nome_video', '$disciplina', '$link_video', '$coment_video', 'Nenhum arquivo', NOW())";
      $exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error($conection));
  }

?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php

Achei este tópico que deve possuir algo a respeito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode extrair o ID dos links do Youtube utilizando as ferramentas de manipulação de URL do PHP.

```php
$url = $_POST['link_video'];
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $saida_de_variaveis);
echo $saida_de_variaveis['v'];    // obtém o parâmetro 'v' da url 
  // Saída: NZta28cFU3w
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/lx4nQy).</sup>

Então, quando quiser este ID, você pode associar à uma variável com:

```
$id_do_video = $saida_de_variaveis['v'];
```

Isso ocorre porque o `parse_url` analisa a URL de entrada e retorna os parâmetros que nela estão inseridos. O `parse_string` obtém os resultados para um *array* chamado `$saida_de_variaveis`.